# Multiple images upload code not working. What am I missing?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android app in which the user will be asked to upload 2 images from his phone gallery.

My activity has one "Upload" button + 2 ImageViews to show the selected images before proceeding to the next activity.

Everything seems to work fine but both ImageViews are filled with just one of the images I select and I don't know why.

I searched on Google and on this website finding a lot of similar questions, but none of them helped me. Since I'm not an expert I could be missing something stupid and easy, but I'm quite lost at this point and decided to create a post.

Here is my Java code from the activity:

```
public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Button and ImageViews have the same names for layout IDs
    Button uploadBtn;
    ImageView imgOne;
    ImageView imgTwo;

    public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;

    public static Uri imgUri1;
    public static Uri imgUri2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

        uploadBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadBtn);

        imgOne = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgOne);
        imgTwo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgTwo);

        uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        gallery.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            imgUri1 = data.getData();
            imgOne.setImageURI(imgUri1);
            imgUri2 = data.getData();
            imgTwo.setImageURI(imgUri2);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works but shows just one selected image for BOTH ImageViews.

Looks like it's skipping the second image and assigns its ImageView to the first one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself after many tries.
The solution was to use a for like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getClipData() != null) {
            int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Uri screen = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                imgUri1 = data.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getUri();
                imgOne.setImageURI(imgUri1);
                imgUri2 = data.getClipData().getItemAt(1).getUri();
                imgTwo.setImageURI(imgUri2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is this piece of code:

```
imgUri1 = data.getData();
imgOne.setImageURI(imgUri1);
imgUri2 = data.getData();
imgTwo.setImageURI(imgUri2);
```

You set `imgUri1` **AND** `imgUri2` to `data.getData()`. So `imgUri1` and `imgUri2` are exact the same. So you set the same `Uri` to both `imageViews`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew something was wrong in that part of the code! I tried to change it a little bit yesterday without success. May I ask you what should be modified to make it work?

Comment: @Pietro I recommend to use 2 different Requestcodes and call 2 different Intents. Then you have 2 different Uris.

Comment: sorry for my late reply. I declared one more requestCode (PICK_IMAGE2 = 200) and added another Intent inside openGallery, but the problem still persists and now my app opens gallery two times. Is there a way to use more requestCodes for an Intent and startActivityForResult? I feel I'm missing something little but can't find it.

Comment: @Pietro Do you want to use only one button for opening the gallery?

Comment: Yes, I would like to click on one single upload button, select 2 pictures from gallery and store/show them in their ImageViews. Thanks to your reply I understood where is the problem, but I still can't figure out the right code to use. I'm trying everything

Answer (score 0):

Maybe should set data to array `data[0]=data1fromimg1` and `data[1]=data2fromimg1`

in your code like this

```
<br>
imgUri1 = data[0].getData();<br>
imgOne.setImageURI(imgUri1);<br>
imgUri2 = data[1].getData();<br>
imgTwo.setImageURI(imgUri2);
```

make sure that receive data

Comment: Hey man thanks for the answer. I considered the idea of creating an array but it looks I can't define it for "data" inside `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data[])`. Am I missing something?